# is there a depth option for np.vectorize()

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

i'll explain what i mean by this example

i converted an image to a 3D-np.array of this form [row * col * [r, g, b, alpha, x,y]]

Notes:

- The 3rd dimension is a numpy array containing rgba values of the pixel as well as its coordinates
- To be presize rgb values are integers beetween 0 and 255

i want to modify each pixel(img[row][col]) using a function _func and am not sure if i can use np.vectorize for this

an example of _func would be to convert the pixel array to change the pixel rgb values st they are all equal (by calculating their mean) so that the pixel becomes gray (_func dosent modify the alpha or x, y of the pixel)

_func(np.array([100, 50, 0, 100, 255, 0, 0])) -> np.array([50, 50, 50, 100, 255, 0, 0])

can someone show me somthing equivelant to this code that actually works

```
#imports
img = f(img.bmp)   #convert img to numpyarray, f defined earlier
def _func(arr):
    "_func implementation here"

func = np.vectorize(_func, depth=2)  #depth=2 because there is rows and columns
new_img = func(img)
```

i that this depth parameter dosent exist but can i implement this somehow.

and thank you for any help
(btw i started learning numpy this evening to do a little fun-project so i am very beginner at numpy)

Comment: Don't try to use `np.vectorize`.  It doesn't help with speed, and it's not worth fighting its default behavior.

Comment: `np.vectorize` has a `signature` parameter that allows passing arrays to your function, but in most testing it is slower.  I don't recommend it, though I've debugged its use for some SO.

Comment: Yeah, to be more direct, your example problem is easy to solve with standard numpy operations and functions, and the solution will be 50x faster at a minimum. Is the example problem actually what you want to do? If your real problem can't be solved with ordinary numpy, you should most likely use [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) instead.