Vectorize a Numpy Function
For instance, I want to vectorize the function that returns a determinant of a matrix.
So I try the following codes:
data1test=np.random.rand(2,2)
data2test=np.random.rand(2,2)
data3test=np.random.rand(2,2)
data4test=np.random.rand(2,2)
fulldata=np.array((data1test,data2test,data3test,data4test))

def det_vec():
    return np.vectorize(np.linalg.det)
myfunc=det_vec()
myfunc(fulldata)

However, it returns a "LinAlgError: 0-dimensional array given. Array must be at least two-dimensional" error.
Can anyone show me what is the problem? Thank you!

If I'm not mistaken, what's happening is that numpy is trying to take the determinant of each individual element in each of your arrays, rather than only mapping the function to each test array. Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67359587/is-there-a-depth-option-for-np-vectorize might be relevant.

What does the det docs specify?  Input is (..., M, M) array_like, that it is it takes a multidim array whose last 2 dimensions are the same.  And returns a (...) result - i.e. det of each (M,M) subarray.  What's fulldata.shape?

Don't use np.vectorize without actually reading (and trying to understand) its docs.  Pay attention to what it actually says, not what you wish it did.  vectorize passes scalar values to your function - unless you specify the signature, which is slower.  It is not a "performance" tool.

Your vectorized function is vectorizing too deeply, it would seem.
You can use the signature argument to get around this and force vectorization at only the top level:
>>> myfunc = np.vectorize(np.linalg.det, signature="(a,b,c)->(a)")
>>> myfunc((np.eye(2), np.array([[1,3],[4,2]])))
array([  1., -10.])

Edit: It's worth mentioning that @hpaulj is right - explicit vectorization isn't even necessarily needed here. See the following:
>>> np.linalg.det((np.eye(2), np.array([[1,3],[4,2]])))
array([  1., -10.])

